# I have a US B-1 visa and am planning to transit via Seattle to go to India from Canada

Tags: short-connections, sea

I have a valid US B-1 visa, so just wanted to check if I can transit via Seattle.

And if my connection flight is only 1.30 hours, will I be still able to  make it?

Comment: I am unclear about what you're asking.  Are you asking if 1 hour 30 minutes enough for a connection time?  Or are you asking if your B1 visa enough to do the transit in Seattle?

Comment: What airport in Canada do you fly from? It's likely that you will clear the US immigration in Canada. Then 1:30 should be enough.

Comment: Hi Karlson, I want to know 2 things. 1) Can i transit via Seattle with my valid b1 visa 2) If so then my connection flight/layouver period is only 1.30 hours. So will i be able to clear customs within that time.

Comment: @R-traveler, i will be flying from Vancouver

Comment: @JonathanReez How's transiting through USA related to transit visa for Canada?

Comment: @Karlson OP wants to know if he can transit through Canada on the way to the US

Comment: @JonathanReez OP is flying from Canada to India via Seattle.  It is a dupe but not of the Canadian Visa question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are flying from Canada into Seattle then almost surely you will clear the border at the Canadian airport as almost every Canadian airport (Vancouver YVR, Calgary YYC, Toronto YYZ -- Victoria YYJ being the only exception) that has a direct flight to SEA has a US pre-clearance facility.

B1 visa is plenty to enter the USA, yes.

If you cleared the border then 90 minutes is more than enough. Otherwise, you need at least two hours (according to SABRE).